# Delegate function error

Tags: c#

I have following code. dont have any clue why I am getting this error - Delegate Function doesnot take 1 arguments.

I am implementing a global Response handler which will be called by saveral requests.

Here is the HandleResponse function:

```
Response<T> HandleResponse<T>(Func<Response<T>> func)
{
    try
    {
        Response <T> response = func();
        if(response != null)
        {
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            //display response.message
            return default(Response<T>);
        }
    }
    catch(ConnectionException e)
    {
        // func = e.Message.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return default(Response<T>);
    }
}
```

And here is my Calling Function:

```
Request.MyRequest request = new 
Request.MyRequest()
{
     param1= comment, param2 = users
};

SomeResponse response = HandleResponse<SomeResponse>(x => client.DoRequest(request, revision.Name, revision.RevisionNumber));
```

I am a C++ developer and very new to C#. I am not sure why I am getting this error. Please someone explain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try calling HandleRespnse<SomeResponse>(() => client.DoRequest ...) The func doesnt have any input paramters.

Comment: I made my comment an answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `x => client.DoRequest()` you are calling the delegate with 1 Parameter (the `x` before `=>`).

But your delegate has no parameters so you have to call it like this 
`() => client.DoRequest()`

Comment: Hi Tobias, Thanks for replying..I tried that way also Getting different error now(cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the  block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type)

Comment: It is because the lambda your passing has no return value, but you expect it to have Response<T> as return value - or what is DoRequest returning?

Comment: If it is returning `void`, use `Action` instead of `Func`